# Как считывать все пакеты, которые идут по LAN порту?

Tags: lan

Возник вопрос, скажем есть программа она передает какие-то данные по LAN порту, как можно посмотреть какие данные эта программа отправляет и принимает с другого устройства? Может есть какие-нибудь программы или способы посмотреть какие данные между ними передаются?

Comment: Wireshark . . .

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо)